# Noun form of verb "decline"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

Is there a noun form of the verb "to decline"?

That is, is there a word that follows this pattern:

```
to accept  -> acceptance
to decline -> ?
```

I am aware of the word declination which is the closest I've found, but that seems to reflect the meaning of "decline" as related to "incline" and "recline" rather than the synonym of refuse.

If not, are there synonyms of "decline" that follow this pattern?

Comment: I think most US English speakers would use "refusal" as the opposite of "acceptance".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *OED* has *six* nouns formed from *decline* with the meaning you are looking for, but all of them are rare or obsolete:

> **declension** 5. The action of declining. *rare.*
>
> **declinal** *rare.* The action of declining.
>
> **declination** †6. The withholding of acceptance.
>
> † **declinement** = declinature
>
> **declining** 2. Avoidance (*obs.*); non-acceptance; refusal.
>
> **declinature** 2. The action of declining or refusing.

Comment: While it's a gerund rather than a pure noun, I would probably suggest using "declining" to be sure that people would understand. It's less rare than the others.

Answer (score 14):

There is **declination** and **declension**, but neither is commonly used to mean "refusal". At least *declination* has a dictionary sense "refusal", so you could use it to mean that. You could also simply use the gerund *declining* if you have to, but in most cases *refusal* is probably a better choice.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries marks *declination* (in the refusal sense) as American - (e.g. *the mandatory vaccine declination form*.) Perhaps that is why I had never heard of it. But I can think of various instances where it would be preferable to *refusal* which seems far too strong for such things as invitations. Sometimes in Britain it might be said that 'so-and-so sent their *regrets*. We speak of a *regrets letter*.

Comment: In cases where "refusal" is deemed too strong I've often seen "non-acceptance" used instead.

Comment: You may want to add the other (common) meanings of declination, as in irregular verb declination or declination of a star.

Comment: There's also the noun **decline**, but that doesn't mean "refusal", either.

Comment: @oerkelens Do you mean noun declension (rather than verb declination), or is "declination" just an obscure term for "conjugation"?

Comment: @KyleStrand - I always mix them up :( Yes, I mean noun declination / declension

Answer (score 9):

I think you may use;

[Denial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Denial):

> - a refusal to agree or comply with a statement;

[Refusal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/refusal):

> - the act or an instance of refusing

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: @tchrist - source included!!

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the noun forms of *decline* are now disused, so I would recommend a different word altogether.

*Refusal* and *rejection* wouldn't be quite right, since declining is more passive.

I suggest **nonacceptance** (or **non-acceptance**) for most situations.  However, if declining an invitation, **regret** would be a more diplomatic term.

Comment: Yes, "I regret your invitation," does seem more diplomatic, doesn't it?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be diplomatic at all. "I wish to express my regret" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm disinclined to acquiesce to your request. Means "no".

*Captain Barbossa, Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl*

Perhaps "disinclination" suits your description?
1. the absence of inclination; reluctance; unwillingness.

Comment: Neat **!**  Sorry you weren't marked up for this answer. Naming your sources (especially if you can provide a link) earns kudos and melts hearts.